# Asp.net MVC difference between <%: and <%=

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Can somebody explain me the difference between using <%: and <%= in an aspx view of an MVC application.

Thanks, 
Radu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Roughly speaking, `<%=term%>` translates to `Resonse.Write(term)` whereas `<%:term%>` translates to `Response.Write(Html.Encode(term))`

Answer (score 6):

`<%:` does an HTML Encode, whereas `<%=` does not.

Comment: One important note, is that <%: will not re-encode a value that implements IHtmlString (i.e., MvcHtmlString)

Comment: <%: Only does an encode on Text not marked as Encoded already. So since Html.ActionLink(blah blah blah) is already encoded (since it returns an IHtmlString) it will not re-encode it.

Comment: A downvote seems a bit extreme.

Answer (score 2):

[It automatically html encodes the text that is rendered in the webpage.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`<%: %>` will attempt to convert whatever is placed in between it to a string then Html Encodes it and outputs it to the response stream.. However, if the object implements `IHtmlString`, it will NOT encode it.

`<%= %>` will convert whatever is between it to a string and output it to the response stream.

Answer (score 1):

The <%: was a new syntax that came with ASP.NET 4.0 and in effect it automatically HtmlEncodes the contents contained within the tags.

Comment: It came with ASP.NET 4.0 - it also works with webforms.

Comment: That's not entirely true. The <%: came with .NET 4. It does not work in earlier versions.

Comment: My mistake, I have edited the answer appropriately.